# Rust Range.contains failed to be inlined/optimized

Tags: optimization, rust, inlining, rust-clippy

I was running my code through Clippy and it suggested changing the following:

```rust
const SPECIAL_VALUE: u8 = 0; // May change eventually.

pub fn version1(value: u8) -> bool {
    (value >= 1 && value <= 9) || value == SPECIAL_VALUE
}
```

Into

```rust
pub fn version2(value: u8) -> bool {
    (1..=9).contains(&value) || value == SPECIAL_VALUE
}
```

Since it is more readable. Unfortunately the resulting assembly output is twice as long, even with optimization level 3. Manually inlining it (2-nestings down), gives almost the same code as `version1` and is as efficient.

```rust
pub fn manually_inlined(value: u8) -> bool {
    (1 <= value && value <= 9) || value == SPECIAL_VALUE
}
```

If I remove the `|| value == SPECIAL_VALUE` they all resolve with the same (though with 1 more instruction added to decrement the parameter value before a compare). Also if I change `SPECIAL_VALUE` to something not adjacent to the range they all resolve to same assembly code as `version2`, which is the reason why I kept it `0` unless I eventually have to change it.

I have a link to Godbolt with the code here: https://rust.godbolt.org/z/bMYzfcYob

Why is the compiler failing to properly inline/optimize `version2`? Is it an "optimization bug"? Or am I misunderstanding some semantics of Rust, maybe something with the borrowing prevents the optimization, but can't the compiler assume no mutation of value due to the aliasing and referencing rules?

Trying to do the same in C++ suggest, yields the worse option in both cases (https://godbolt.org/z/zahfz65W3)

Edit: Changing the compiler for my C++ version to GCC makes it optimized in both cases.

Comment: In general, there is no guarantee for a specific optimization to happen, but this case feels indeed weird. If you don't get a good reply here, I suggest asking on the Rust user forums or filing an issue on GitHub – in particular since this is a change suggested by clippy.

Comment: I've asked on the Rust issue tracker now. If I get an answer, I'll will repeat it here if the answerer does not not do it.

Comment: Here's the issue: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/90609

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was indeed a missed optimization opportunity that has now been corrected in LLVM. https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/90609#issuecomment-1046037263 .